# WPF - Getting static column value in code

Tags: datagrid, static

I want to show edit and delete link in datagrid and if any user clicks on these link I want to perform some actions, so I've bind the hyperlink column with ID field of database, Following is the code sample

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" Header="Junk2"></DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```

Questions:

1. It shows ID value in hyperlink column, I want to show static text "Edit".
2. If any user click on any Edit hyperlink on EDIT Column, I want to get the ID of binding field so I can perform database operations.

Can you please let me know how perform above two tasks?

Comment: You somehow deleted the image attachment

Comment: I don;t have to attach any image, I've rephrase my question

Comment: @Anthon can you please guide me on this?